# how to add a buttons at the bottom of slide drawer menu in android?

Tags: android

I need to add buttons at the bottom of slide drawer menu but if i am adding not getting error on xml but runtime it show errors

please help me to find out where i am wrong

i want this :-

[image]

this my Xml :-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cscart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/cscart" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cscart"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/magento"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/border"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/magento" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/border1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/magento"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/opencart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/border1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/opencart" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/border2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/opencart"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/border2"
        >

        <TableRow>
            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingRight="2dp">

                <Button
        android:id="@+id/abantecart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/abantecart" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp">
               <Button
        android:id="@+id/prestashop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/prestashop" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OUR NEWSLETTER"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:text="Subscribe To Our Newsletter And Be The First To Get Our Latest"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:background="@drawable/email_entry">
    <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/mail_id"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Enter Your Email Address"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/subscribe_mailid" 
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/guarenteed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
    android:text="100% GUARENTEED"
    android:textColor="#ababab"
    android:background="@drawable/gurenteed_color"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/border3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/guarenteed"
        android:background="#ababab"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/membership"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/border3"
    android:text="OUR MEMBERSHIP"
    android:textColor="#ababab"
    android:background="@drawable/gurenteed_color"
    android:textSize="12sp"
/>
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/border4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/membership"
        android:background="#ababab"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/secure_payment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/border4"
    android:text="100% SECURE PAYMENT"
    android:textColor="#ababab"
    android:background="@drawable/gurenteed_color"
    android:textSize="12sp"
/>
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/border5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secure_payment"
        android:background="#ababab"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/forum_access"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/border5"
    android:text="24X7 FORUM ACCESS"
    android:textColor="#ababab"
    android:background="@drawable/gurenteed_color"
    android:textSize="12sp"
/>
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/border6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forum_access"
        android:background="#ababab"/>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3a3439"
    android:layout_below="@+id/border6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/facebook"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/twitter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/link_add"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="310dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/copyright"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/link"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start">
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@drawable/slidemenu_back"/>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="b1"/>
     <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="b1"/>
     <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="b1"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

main activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    //private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    public static int cart;
    static boolean read=true;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    String mail_id;
    int code;
    static boolean changebackground=true;
    //expandable listview
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView mDrawerList;;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    //expandable listview
    TextView totalitems;
    DatabaseHandler data;
    ImageView gotocart;
    List<String> OurTemplates;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        changebackground=false;




        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar,
                null);

 ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // Set up your ActionBar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

actionBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

       Button menu=(Button) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.menu);

     totalitems=(TextView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.detail_totalcartitem);
        data=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());



        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //  mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerList.setGroupIndicator(null);
     prepareListData();
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), true, ""));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();



        //expandable listview






        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                /
                int pos=childPosition;
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                changebackground=true;

                if(pos==0)
                {
                // Adding child data
                listDataHeader.add("E-commerce Templates");


                // Adding child data
                List<String> E_commerce = new ArrayList<String>();
                E_commerce.add("Cs-Cart");
                E_commerce.add("Magento");
                E_commerce.add("Opencart");
                E_commerce.add("Prestashop");
                E_commerce.add("Abantecart");
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), E_commerce); 

                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                // setting list adapter
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==1)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("CMS Templates");
                    List<String> CMS = new ArrayList<String>();
                    CMS.add("Wordpress");
                    CMS.add("Drupal");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), CMS); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==2)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("Video Sharing Templates");
                    List<String> video_sharing = new ArrayList<String>();
                    video_sharing.add("Clipshare");
                    video_sharing.add("Phpmotion");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), video_sharing); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==3)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("Social Networking Templates");
                    List<String> social_networking = new ArrayList<String>();
                    social_networking.add("Dolphin");
                    social_networking.add("Socialengine");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), social_networking); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==4)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("Free Templates");
                    List<String> free_templates = new ArrayList<String>();
                    free_templates.add("Cs-Cart");
                    free_templates.add("Magento");
                    free_templates.add("Opencart");
                    free_templates.add("Prestashop");
                    free_templates.add("Dolphine");
                    free_templates.add("Drupal");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), free_templates); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }


                return false;
            }
        });





        ;

menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);

                }
                else if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);


                }

            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name 
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("E-commerce Templates");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(0);
        }




    }


    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //fragment = new Home();
            // click();

            ///mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, CsCart.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 2:
             click();
            break;
        case 3:
             click();
            break;
        case 4:
             click();
            break;
        case 5:
             click();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    void click()
    {

        navDrawerItems.clear();


    }


    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Home");
        listDataHeader.add("Our Templates");
        listDataHeader.add("Our Services");
        listDataHeader.add("Portfolio");
        listDataHeader.add("Add-ons");
        listDataHeader.add("Blog");
        listDataHeader.add("Forum");
        listDataHeader.add("Contact us");


        // Adding child data
        OurTemplates = new ArrayList<String>();
        OurTemplates.add("E-commerce Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("CMS Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("Video Sharing Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("Social Networking Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("Free Templates");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),new ArrayList<String>() );
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), OurTemplates);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), new ArrayList<String>());// Header, Child data

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }

}
```

at the run time i am getting error like this

```
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086): Process: com.bugtreat.shopping, PID: 1086
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:844)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1096)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.bugtreat.shopping.MainActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:586)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2556)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-16 02:59:47.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Look at which line the error is on. On that line you are trying to assign an element different `LayoutParams` to what the item needs. In your case the item requires `DrawerLayout.LayoutParams` and you are trying to assign `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`